# Mongoose - FindById

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to retrieve a doc from database by its id? The `findOne()` and `find()` querys executes as expected but the `findById()` does not, it returns a null value. What am I doing wrong??? I've tried hard coding an id and it still returns null.

```
const getLocation = async (req, res) => {
  let docById = {};
  let docByField = {};
  Location.findById(req.params.id, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) return res.send(err);
    docById = doc;
  });
  Location.findOne({ flag: "post" }, function (err, doc) {
    console.log(doc);
    if (err) return res.send(err);
    docByField = doc;
  });
  let collection = await Location.find();
  return res.json({params: req.params, docById, docByField, collection });
};
```

Postman
`localhost:3000/api/location/5f5fc279ff1d07315cc76a8a`

```
{
    "params": {
        "id": "5f5fc279ff1d07315cc76a8a"
    },
    "docById": null,
    "docByField": {
        "coordinates": [
            12.2384,
            47.4309843
        ],
        "_id": "5f641abaa8ac9049a0e40c18",
        "__v": 0,
        "flag": "post",
        "type": "Point"
    },
    "collection": [
        {
            "coordinates": [
                -73.856077,
                40.848447
            ],
            "_id": "5f5fc279ff1d07315cc76a8a",
            "type": "Point",
            "flag": "profile"
        },
        {
            "coordinates": [
                12.2384,
                47.4309843
            ],
            "_id": "5f641abaa8ac9049a0e40c18",
            "__v": 0,
            "flag": "post",
            "type": "Point"
        }
    ]
}
```

**SOLVED**

```
//transform string into id object
const { Types } = require("mongoose");
const toObjId = (id) => {
  return Types.ObjectId(id);
};

const getLocation = async (req, res) => {
  await Location.findById(toObjId(req.params.id), function (err, doc) {
    if (err) return res.send(err);
    return res.send(doc);
  });
};
```

Comment: Try adding a `console.log(doc)` in the callback function of `findById`. There is a chance that the `getLocation` function returns the response before the callback of the `findById` method is called.

Comment: console log is showing null as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by transforming the id into a ObjectId before passing it to the query. Also, make sure you await the query, even when passing a callback. Hope this helps the next person q:

```
//transform string into id object
const { Types } = require("mongoose");
const toObjId = (id) => {
  return Types.ObjectId(id);
};

const getLocation = async (req, res) => {
  await Location.findById(toObjId(req.params.id), function (err, doc) {
    if (err) return res.send(err);
    return res.send(doc);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```js
console.log(req.params.id)
Location.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }).then(data => console.log(data))
```

OR

```js
Location.findById(req.params.id).then(data => console.log(data))
```

Just checking maybe it has something to do with the structure of how you are laying out.

We need to make sure that we get the id correctly, and console.log() immediately to make sure all variables are occupied.

Comment: Niether of the functions returned a doc. console log is logging the id.